# scrollHeight is being read before animations finish, resulting in a wrong maxHeight value

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I'm trying to make an Accordion element and I want the items to expand smoothly. Currently, the padding is being read too early, which results in it not being factored into the scrollHeight properly, which makes the accordion bodies too small each time. How do I make scrollHeight factor in the padding post-animation?

AccordionItem.js:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import AccordionContext from './AccordionContext'
import './Accordion.css'

const AccordionItem = ({children, title}) => {
    const [openItem, setOpenItem] = useContext(AccordionContext)
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
    const itemRef = useRef(null)
    const bodyRef = useRef(null)

    const onClick = () => {
        (openItem === itemRef) ? setOpenItem(null) : setOpenItem(itemRef)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        isOpen() ? setHeight(Math.min(400, bodyRef.current.scrollHeight)) : setHeight(0)
    }, [openItem])

    const isOpen = () => {
        return openItem === itemRef
    }

    return (
        <div className={"accordion-item " + (isOpen() ? 'open ' : '')} ref={itemRef}>
            <div className={"accordion-title "} onClick={onClick}>
                {title}
            </div>
            <div
                className="accordion-body"
                ref={bodyRef}
                style={{maxHeight: height + 'px'}}
            >
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AccordionItem
```

Accordion.css:

```
.accordion-item {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion-title {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ff77fb;

    border: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.3) 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.accordion-title::after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;

    background-image: url('../../static/images/arrow.svg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    filter: invert(40%) sepia(62%) saturate(6471%) hue-rotate(305deg) brightness(96%) contrast(96%);
    /* For a different color: https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp */

    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.accordion-item.open .accordion-title::after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-body {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: scroll;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out, padding 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordion-item.open .accordion-body {
    padding: 18px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```